# Which devices in /sys/block are HDDs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, proc

I'm interested which devices in /sys/block are real HDD drives:

```
[root@sdp1a block]# pwd
/sys/block
[root@sdp1a block]# ls
dm-0   dm-12  dm-3  dm-7   loop1  loop5  ram1   ram13  ram3  ram7  sdaa  sdae  sdai  sdam  sdaq  sdau  sday  sdbb  sdbf  sdc  sdg  sdk  sdo  sds  sdw
dm-1   dm-13  dm-4  dm-8   loop2  loop6  ram10  ram14  ram4  ram8  sdab  sdaf  sdaj  sdan  sdar  sdav  sdaz  sdbc  sdbg  sdd  sdh  sdl  sdp  sdt  sdx
dm-10  dm-14  dm-5  dm-9   loop3  loop7  ram11  ram15  ram5  ram9  sdac  sdag  sdak  sdao  sdas  sdaw  sdb   sdbd  sdbh  sde  sdi  sdm  sdq  sdu  sdy
dm-11  dm-2   dm-6  loop0  loop4  ram0   ram12  ram2   ram6  sda   sdad  sdah  sdal  sdap  sdat  sdax  sdba  sdbe  sdbi  sdf  sdj  sdn  sdr  sdv  sdz
[root@sdp1a block]#
```

How I can understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Whether a block device is a real HDD can be derived from the major device number corresponding to the disk driver as documented in `man sd` and `man 4 hd`:
SCSI and SATA disks have major 8, old IDE disks 3 or 22.

You can see these in `/proc/devices` or parse the `/sys/block/*/dev` files:
`cd /sys/block; grep -lE '^(8|3|22):' */dev | sed 's-/dev--'`
`sda`
`sdb`

When this is run in a virtual machine, results depend on virtualization type:
With [Hardware virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization), behavior is as above except for PVHVM (see below).
With [Paravirtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization), things change. For instance, XEN xvd driver uses major 202.
This is also true for [PVHVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PVHVM#Types_of_virtualization) as used on Amazon EC2, for example.
Thus you need additional measures to achieve your desired result on VMs.